# Import file from previous directory?

Tags: python, path, sys

To reference particular functions, I use  `sys.path.append("./lib")`
but in these functions it was necessary for me to read a txt from the main directory

```
config=configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("run.def")
```

so, how can I return or reference path to the previous directory (because I am in the lib directory) ??

```
./
├── main.py
├── run.def
└── lib
    ├── output.py
    ├──
    ├──
```

Comment: What is previous deirectory?

Comment: Add the code snippet and paths in your question.

Comment: The previous folder is general, and i added a graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one served me

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go up one directory from a given directory you can use ../. So if you want to go up one directory from ./lib you can write `./lib/../`